# VCF in imessage crashing due to customized CNSocialProfile service name?

Tags: swift, imessage, cncontact, vcf-vcard, ios10.3

I have created a vcf programatically using swift . In this vcf i have made a `[CNLabeledValue<CNSocialProfile>]` object , on which i have appended a `CNSocialProfile` with custom service name , in my case its **"Instagram"** .

But as soon as i share this vcf using iMessage , all devices operating on iOS 13 above crashes on clicking the vcf , but all the devices prior to iOS 13 has been working fine. Is there any way to avoid this for time being ?

This issue being custom service name in `CNSocialProfile` is obtained by manual testing the same and indvidually removing one element at a time as its not possible to debug iMessage app(i think).

This is the code which caused the issue:

```
if contact.instagram != ""
{
    socialProfiles.append(
        CNLabeledValue(
            label: "Instagram", 
            value: CNSocialProfile(
                urlString: contact.instagram, 
                username: contact.instagram, 
                userIdentifier: self.givenName, 
                service: CNSocialProfile.localizedString(
                    forService:"Instagram"
                )
            )
        )
    )
}
```

I want to display the custom social media links like instagram and snapchat **without crashing the vcf sent through iMessage** as its essential to the working of the app. Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently as of iOS 13.2.3 , this bug exits in iMessage app . The reason for this is due to unsupported custom label for `CNSocialProfile` .

There is a work around for the same . You can have customised label in `urladdress` array of `CNMutableContact` .

Also birthday is also not saving in contacts post iOS 13. Hope apple fixes it soon.